# Rebus - which side is it?

Tags: rebus

Which side is it?   Nice blue arrows.

[image: Which side is it?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UP - side - DOWN

So the answer is:

> **Upside down**

Answer (score 1):

> Up side down

Because

> First arrow points **up**, then the word **side** comes, and the next arrow points **down**.